# match part of names in data.frame to new column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data.frame with one column of Sample.Names. The Names contain information where the samples are from. For instance c(RT4_4, RT3_6, RT4_2, RT3_9, RT5_5) RTx is the name of the site they are from and then follows a number.

I want a new columns that gives me the information were they are from. If Sample.Names contains RT4 -> df$Site == RT4

I don't know if there is a functions that allows you to look at part of the name my idea was

`df$Site <- with(df, ifelse(df$Sample.Name %in% "RT4","RT4", ifelse(df$Sample.Name %in% "RT3","RT3","RT5")))`

this doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sub`:

```
df$Site <- sub("_.+", "", df$Sample.Name)
```

This works with numbers consisting of multiple digits too.